# How do I rewrite this line to avoid the "#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []" error?

Tags: ruby, model, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, entity-relationship

I have these models ...

```
class Administrator < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_many :locations


class Location < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_many :displays, :dependent => :destroy
```

I had this code that is meant to retrieve all displays subject to certain criteria ...

```
  @displays = []
  current_user.locations.each do |location|
    @displays = (@displays + location.displays.where(:user => user).includes(:administrator)).uniq
  end
```

I wanted to find a slick Rails way to simplify the above into a one liner, so I tried this

```
  @displays = current_user.locations.displays.where(:user => user).includes(:administrator).flatten.uniq
```

but this results in an error

```
undefined method `displays' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Is there a way to rewrite my intiial block in a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class method to your `Location` model to achieve the result you want.

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :displays, dependent: :destroy

  def self.displays
    Display.where(location_id: select(:id))
  end
end
```

Which should allow you to use:

```
@displays = current_user.locations.displays.where(user: user).includes(:administrator)
```

---

If you don't want to add a helper to your model, you could change up your record fetching technique.

```
location_ids = current_user.locations.pluck(:id)
@displays = Display.where(location_id: location_ids, user: user).includes(:administrator)
```

For a single line you can simply merge the above lines together. However I would go for the multi-line solution, since this line will get pretty long.

```
@displays = Display.where(location_id: current_user.locations.pluck(:id), user: user).includes(:administrator)
```

---

In both these scenario there is no need to `flatten` or call `uniq` on the result.

You might want to swap `select(:id)` out for `pluck(:id)` or vice versa. The difference being that `select` will create a subquery. While `pluck` first performs a query only fetching the location ids, then use them to create a new query. This does produce an additional query, but might be faster since the queries are less complex.

You also might be able to use the following scope instead of a class method:

```
scope :displays, -> { Display.where(location_id: select(:id)) }
```

The reason I've used a class method is for definition/consistency reasons. Let me quote the [definition of "scope"](https://www.wordnik.com/words/scope) from the GNU version of the Collaborative International Dictionary of English:

> *noun* That at which one aims; the thing or end to which the mind directs its view; that which is purposed to be reached or accomplished; hence, ultimate design, aim, or purpose; intention; drift; object.

From the above we can conclude that scopes should add restrictions on the current scope to narrow the aim of the result. Scopes should therefore only return restricted versions of the current scope. Since `displays` returns a completely new scope, with a different resulting records (instances of `Display` instead of `Location`) I've opted for a class method instead. (Although usage is the same.)

Comment: Thanks for this breakdown.  ULtimately I went with your one-line solution, "Display.where(location_id: current_user.locations.pluck(:id), user: user).includes(:administrator)".  Putting some of it on different lines made the formatting nice.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `displays` on `locations` and not `location`.

You might be looking for something like:

`current_user.locations.joins(:displays).where(displays: { user: user }) ...`

Comment: Thanks, but can you fill in the rest of the "..."s?  The statement should return "displays" but as you have it, it's returning "locations".

Comment: No they cannot.  There is no relationship from user to any of the other entities, it is purely just a where clause param.  Administrator has_many locations, which has_many displays.